# Cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 - Kotlin - AndroidX - Dagger 2.17

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, androidx

**Short error log**:

```
> :presentation:transformDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDebug
> e: E:\MVVM\presentation\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\mvvm\ui\base\BaseActivity.java:9: error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23
public abstract class BaseActivity extends dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity {
                ^
  class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: java.lang.AssertionError: annotation tree hasn't been attributed yet: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 11}, bv = {1, 0, 2}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\f\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\b&\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002\u00a8\u0006\u0003"}, d2 = {"Lcom/example/mvvm/ui/base/BaseActivity;", "Ldagger/android/support/DaggerAppCompatActivity;", "()V", "presentation_debug"})
```

**Libraries' verions**:

```
ext{
minSdkVersion = 14
targetSdkVersion = 28
androidCompileSdkVersion = 28
testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
androidPluginVersion = '3.1.4'
kotlinVersion = '1.2.70'
supportVersion = '1.0.0-alpha1'
daggerVersion = '2.17'
roomVersion = '2.0.0-beta01'
lifecycleVersion = '2.0.0-beta01'
rxJavaVersion = '2.2.2'
rxAndroidVersion = '2.1.0'
supportTest = '1.1.0-alpha1'
multidexVersion = '2.0.0'
...
}

kotlin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}",
rxJava: "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${rxJavaVersion}",
rxAndroid: "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion",
appCompat: "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$supportVersion",
material: "com.google.android.material:material:$supportVersion",
supportv4: "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$supportVersion",
appcompatv7: "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$supportVersion",
recyclerview: "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$supportVersion",
cardview: "androidx.cardview:cardview:$supportVersion",
annotation: "androidx.annotation:annotation:$supportVersion",
javaxInject: "javax.inject:javax.inject:$javaxInjectVersion",
dagger: "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}",
daggerAndroid: "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:${daggerVersion}",
daggerAndroidSupport: "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${daggerVersion}",
daggerAndroidProcessor: "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-    processor:${daggerVersion}",
daggerCompiler: "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}",
room: "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion",
roomCompiler: "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion",
roomCommon: "androidx.room:room-common:$roomVersion",
constraintLayout: "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintLayoutVersion",
multidex: "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidexVersion",
lifecycleExtensions: "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycleVersion",
lifecycleCommon: "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycleVersion"
...
```

**Android Studio version**: 3.1.4

**BaseActivity**:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity()
```

**MyApplication**:

```
class MyApplication : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {

        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this)
    }
}
```

**AppComponent**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ViewModelBuilder::class,
    AppModule::class,
    BaseModule::class
])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MyApplication>()
}
```

**AppModule**:

```
@Module(includes = [NetModule::class, DbModule::class])
abstract class AppModule {

    @ApplicationContext
    @Binds
    abstract fun provideApplicationContext(myApplication: MyApplication): Context
}
```

**Full error log**:

```
:presentation:transformDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDebug
> e: E:\MVVM\presentation\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\mvvm\ui\base\BaseActivity.java:9: error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23
public abstract class BaseActivity extends dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity {
                ^
  class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: java.lang.AssertionError: annotation tree hasn't been attributed yet: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 11}, bv = {1, 0, 2}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\f\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\b&\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002\u00a8\u0006\u0003"}, d2 = {"Lcom/example/mvvm/ui/base/BaseActivity;", "Ldagger/android/support/DaggerAppCompatActivity;", "()V", "presentation_debug"})
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:441)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1020)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1062)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1019)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:440)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: annotation tree hasn't been attributed yet: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 11}, bv = {1, 0, 2}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\f\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\b&\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002\u00a8\u0006\u0003"}, d2 = {"Lcom/example/mvvm/ui/base/BaseActivity;", "Ldagger/android/support/DaggerAppCompatActivity;", "()V", "presentation_debug"})
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.checkNonNull(Assert.java:118)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.validateTypeAnnotation(Check.java:2745)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr$TypeAnnotationsValidator.visitAnnotation(Attr.java:4484)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCAnnotation.accept(JCTree.java:2317)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.visitModifiers(TreeScanner.java:315)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCModifiers.accept(JCTree.java:2343)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr$TypeAnnotationsValidator.visitClassDef(Attr.java:4566)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.validateTypeAnnotations(Attr.java:4473)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$2.run(TypeAnnotations.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:155)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:213)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:178)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:95)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:375)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:366)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:120)
    ... 30 more

 > :presentation:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

 > FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 > * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':presentation:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

I've read all of related questions such as:

- [Cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928223/cannot-access-activitycompatapi23-class)
- [Cannot acces ActivityCompatApi23 when trying to use FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677543/cannot-acces-activitycompatapi23-when-trying-to-use-fragmentactivity)
- [Error:(59, 8) error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072953/error59-8-error-cannot-access-activitycompatapi23-class-file-for-android-su?rq=1)
- [cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016661/cannot-access-activitycompatapi23-class-file)
- [cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class file for ActivityCompatApi23 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463834/cannot-access-activitycompatapi23-class-file-for-activitycompatapi23-not-found)
- [Error:(59, 8) error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072953/error59-8-error-cannot-access-activitycompatapi23-class-file-for-android-su)
- ...

All of them say that the support libraries' versions are not the same; Or the `compileSdkVersion` have to be **28**.

I've considered all of these but the error still exists!

I think there is something wrong/missed with using **androidx**, **kotlin**, and **dagger**; But I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Please file a bug to the Kotlin issue tracker: https://kotl.in/issue.

Comment: @yanex Chris Banes somehow did this. > https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1245#issuecomment-421694325

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, set `databinding` to false, to see is there any resources/layout errors or not. (Which in my case, it was for the first error. Yes, there came other errors which I didn't paste it in the question anymore).
- Set `multiDexEnabled true` in your app module's `build.gradle`, inside of `defaultConfig` scope (Or in `data` and `presentation` modules' `build.gradle` files if you're following a Clean Architecture, like me).
- Add below snippet code to `data` and `presentation`'s `build.gradle` files:

  ```
  android {    
  ...
  compileOptions {
      targetCompatibility 1.8
      sourceCompatibility 1.8
  }
  ```
- Don't forget to set `databinding` to true again.
- Change Build Gradle Tools version to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha11'`
- Adding this line to your `local.properties` file: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m`; Of course, according to your hardware config.
- Use Gradle distributation version upper than 4.4. Like: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-all.zip`. (Inside `gradle-wrapper.properties` file).
- Add below snippet code to your CustomMyApplication:

  ```
  override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
      super.attachBaseContext(base)
      MultiDex.install(this)
  }
  ```
- Add below lines to your `gradle.properties` file:

  ```
  android.useAndroidX=true
  # Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
  android.enableJetifier=true
  ```
- Change supportVersion key to `supportVersion = '1.0.0-rc02'//'1.0.0-alpha1'`
- **Change daggerVersion key to** `daggerVersion = '2.16'//2.17`
- Change roomVersion key to `roomVersion = '2.0.0-alpha1'//'2.0.0-beta01'`

Sources:
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1245
[Androidx and databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459728/androidx-and-databinding)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41100670/421467
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48531191/421467
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49525685/421467
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes#july_2_2018
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1270#issuecomment-388449463